# Search if a field exists in sql db

Tags: android

i have a db with KEY_NUMERO as a UNIQUE.First to create a new row i want check if another field have the same KEY_NUMERO.

```
public boolean playerExists(int inputText) throws SQLException {
      Cursor mCursor = null;
       mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NUMERO, KEY_NOME, KEY_COGNOME, KEY_RUOLO},KEY_NUMERO+"="+inputText, null, null, null, null, null);
      boolean result=mCursor.moveToFirst();
      return result;
     }
```

why return always TRUE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you don't get data from you db. You should check with `mCursor.getInt(0)` there will be the `KEY_ROWID` of the current possition of the cursor.

But why did you not use a autoincrement for you db?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html this is a very good tutorial for sqlite. Under point 4.3 you can see who he works with autoincrement for a id